# xls to csv using POI where excel having other language like japanese ie. UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, excel, csv, utf-8, apache-poi

xls to csv using POI where excel having other language like japanese ie. UTF-8 characters

```
 // For storing data into CSV files
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
        try 
        {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        // Get the workbook object for XLS file
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Cell cell;
        Row row;

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
        {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                        cell = cellIterator.next();

                        switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                        {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");
                                break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");
                                break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");
                                break;

                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                                data.append("" + ",");
                                break;

                        default:
                                data.append(cell + ",");
                        }

                        data.append('\n'); 
                }
        }

        fos.write(data.toString().getBytes());
        fos.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
                File inputFile = new File("C:\test.xls");
                File outputFile = new File("C:\output.csv");
                xls(inputFile, outputFile);
        }
```

here the issue is i have cell values having other language charaters like テスト,再テスト1,498レッドアップルコート . when i use above code the csv file is getting create but having values as "??????"

i tried with below also

```
sValue = cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
```

still unable to convert those word

please help me . thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you specify an encoding when you write the file out, as any Java + text file processing tutorial will recommend?

Comment: if i write to text file it is working fine but to csv it not working

Comment: A CSV file is nothing else than a text file having a special ordering of the text (**C**omma  (or other delimiter) **S**eparated **V**alues) but the encoding is not different from a text file. So I suspect the problem is not the encoding but how you are opening the CSV file. Open it using a text editor. Is it OK? Now open it using Excel's [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) and set the "File origin" to `Windows (ANSI)` in step 1. Is it OK?

Comment: Since you are using `fos.write(data.toString().getBytes())`, this encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the **platform's default charset**, storing the result into a new byte array. So depending on your **platform's default charset**, other "File origin" settings in step 1 of the Excel's Text Import Wizard also could be correct. `65001: Unicode (UTF-8)` for example. Better you should explicit set a encoding using [String.getBytes(Charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-).

Answer (score 0):

OK, because of many misunderstandings about text encoding[see:note1] and because of the inability of `Microsoft` to provide `Unicode` support simply usable for `CSV` in `Excel`, let's have a concrete example:

Following `Excel` file:

[image]

and following code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

class ReadExcelWriteCSV {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("inputFile.xls"));

  StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   String delimiter = "";
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    data.append(delimiter);

    switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
     case STRING:
      data.append(cell.getStringCellValue());
      break;
     //case ...

     default:
      System.out.println("default cell"); //should never occur
    }

    delimiter = ",";
   }
   data.append("\r\n"); 
  }

  System.out.println(data);

  BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("outputFile.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

  bwr.write('\ufeff'); //write the UTF-8 BOM to make Excel able to detect UTF-8 encoding
  bwr.write(data.toString());
  bwr.flush();
  bwr.close();

  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

produces a `outputFile.csv` having text encoding `UTF-8`. It also has a [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) which makes it easy determinable to be `UTF-8` encoded. This is necessary because else `Excel` cannot properly detect this encoding while simply opening the `CSV` file by double click.

If we are opening the resulting `outputFile.csv` using a text editor, it should be shown properly and the editor should be able correct detecting `UTF-8` encoding.

If we are opening the resulting `outputFile.csv` using [Text Import Wizard](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Text-Import-Wizard-c5b02af6-fda1-4440-899f-f78bafe41857) in `Excel`, then in the step 1 we also should be able correct setting `UTF-8` encoding:

[image]

The Text Import Wizard looks a little bit different in Office 365:

[image]

Note: Images are from German Excel.

And because of the `BOM` even if simply opened in `Excel` by double click the file, it should be shown properly because of `UTF-8` encoding detected properly.

[note1]: To only talk about one misunderstanding: You are writing about "UTF-8 characters". This is nonsense. There are `Unicode` characters which may be **encoded** using `UTF-8`. `UTF-8` is an encoding and **not** a character set.